# MongoDB: Several fields to a list

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I currently have a collection that follows a format like this:

```
{ "_id": ObjectId(...),
  "name" : "Name",
  "red": 0,
  "blue": 0,
  "yellow": 1,
  "green": 0,
  ...}
```

and so on (a bunch of colors). What I would like to do is to create a new array named `colors`, whose elements are those colors that have a value of 1.

For example:

```
{ "_id": ObjectId(...),
  "name" : "Name",
  "colors": ["yellow"]
}
```

Is this something I can do on the Mongo shell? Or should I do it in a program?
I'm pretty sure I can do it using Python, however I am having difficulties trying to do it directly in the shell. If it can be done in the shell, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can be easily done in the shell, or basically by following the example adapted into any language.

The key here is to look at the fields that are "colors" then contruct an update statement that both removes those fields from the document while testing them to see if they are valid for inclusion into the array, then of course adding that to the document update as well:

```js
var bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp(),
    count = 0;

db.collection.find().forEach(function(doc) { 

    doc.colors = doc.colors || [];

    var update = { "$unset": {}};
    Object.keys(doc).filter(function(key) { 
        return !/^_id|name|colors/.test(key) 
    }).forEach(function(key) {
        update.$unset[key] = "";
        if ( doc[key] == 1)
            doc.colors.push(key);
    });

    update["$addToSet"] = { "colors": { "$each": doc.colors } };

    bulk.find({ "_id": doc._id }).updateOne(update);
    count++;

    if ( count % 1000 == 0 ) {
        bulk.execute();
        bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp()
    }

});

if ( count % 1000 != 0 )
    bulk.execute();
```

The [Bulk Operations](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/) usage means that batches of updates are sent rather than one request and response per document, so this will process a lot faster than merely issuing singular updates back and forth.

The main operators here are [`$unset`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/) to remove the existing fields and [`$addToSet`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) to add the new evaluated array. Both are built up by cycling the keys of the document that make up the possible colors and excluding the other keys you don't want to modify using a regex filter.

Also using `$addToSet` and this line:

```js
    doc.colors = doc.colors || [];
```

with the purpose of being sure that if any document was already partially converted or otherwise touched by a code change that had already started storing the correct array, then these would not be adversely affected or overwritten by the update process.

Answer (score 1):

[tl;dr, spoiler](https://gist.github.com/sgnl/f9a5cc2c4807f3d60dcc)

Mongodb's shell has access to some javascript-like methods on their objects. You can query your collection with [`db.yourCollectionName.find()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) which will return a cursor ([cursor methods](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/js-cursor/)). Then iterate through to get each document, iterate through the keys, conditionally filter out keys like `_id` and `name` and then check to see if the value is `1`, store that key somewhere in a collection.

Once done, you'd probably want to use [`db.yourCollectionName.update()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) or [`db.yourCollectionName.findAndModify()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/) to find the record by `_id` and use `$set` to add a new field and set it's value to the collection of keys.